# Haskell compile: the interface to load is a member of the hidden package (which is itself)

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I hit this when compiling taffybar module. It is very strange that actually claim that I need load this hidden module, which is itself. Error msgs are below:

```
[~/Public/taffybar]-[myMaster↓]── - rm -rf ~/.cache/taffybar && taffybar                                   
Configuration '/home/jethros/.config/taffybar/taffybar.hs' changed. 
Recompiling.
Error occurred while loading configuration file.
Error: 
/home/jethros/.config/taffybar/taffybar.hs:26:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for ‘System.Taffybar.ToggleMonitor’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘taffybar-0.4.6’.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I know in this case it might be hard, but I think it would be ok, if the example included xmonad.

Comment: Otherwise I suspect, that there is an version of Taffybar installed via cabal or stack, which comes prior to your custom one in the search paths. But that is just a suspicion.